# Probability current density spherical wave travelling outwards from a point

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The mathematical representation of a spherical wave travelling outwards from a point is
given by
$$ ψ() = \frac{}{} . ^{}$$

Find out the probability current density () and plot the result

I was taught that $$j(x,t) =\frac{i\hbar}{2m} [ { ψ\frac{dψ^{*}}{dx}}+{ ψ^{*}\frac{dψ}{dx}}]$$ plugging  $ ψ() = \frac{}{} . ^{}$ in the above equation and solving gave me $$j(r)= \frac{-i{\hbar}A^{2}}{r^{3}m}$$   but I had a doubt that can probability current density can be imaginary , if it can be imaginary I was asked to  plot the j(r)  how am I supposed  to do it.

Comment: your original expression for j is clearly imaginary. If you change the plus sign to a minus sign you will end up with something real rather than imaginary. j = ihbar/2m (psi psi*' - psi* psi')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake here is applying a one-dimensional formula for current to a three-dimensional case. The full expression for (non-relativistic) probability current is
$$
\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t)=\frac{\hbar}{2mi}\left[\psi^*(\mathbf{r},t)\nabla\psi(\mathbf{r},t) -
\psi(\mathbf{r},t)\nabla\psi^*(\mathbf{r},t)\right]
$$